# Flutter awesome_extensions package issue

Tags: flutter, dart, package, pubspec, pub.dev

I cloned a project that uses `awesome_extensions package version 2.0.5` but the problem is whenever I run the `flutter pub get` and run the app. It gives the following error that shows the version `2.0.8` is installed.

```
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/awesome_extensions-2.0.8/lib/widget_extensions/padding_extension.dart:44:29: Error: Member not found: 'EdgeInsets.fromViewPadding'.
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromViewPadding(padding, devicePixelRatio),
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the dependency pinned to in your pubspec.yaml? If it's `awesome_extensions: ^2.0.0`, that would explain the issue. If it's `awesome_extensions: 2.0.5`, it should use precisely that version.

Without further information, it's hard to say exactly what's happening. Some basic troubleshooting you can do is clear the packages cache (`dart pub cache clean` followed by `flutter pub get`). Try posting your pubspec.yaml to see if there's any additional information we can glean from it.

Something else you can do is run `flutter pub deps` to view the dependency tree. Perhaps something in there is of use?

Answer (score 0):

try calling, flutter clean, flutter clean cache, go to the folders of /.pub-cache/ and delete everything under /pub.dev/ delete also your pubspec.lock and try again flutter pub get